# Coldfusion, dreamweaver website Security 

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver

I'm creating a Coldfusion website, and am going to need security for it. I know people can add code to comments and change background colour etc. I need to have some code to stop this, along with other issues. I have only managed to find php code for any site security coding. It would really help me to have any coldfusion code for my pages, (for the application page would be even better) to help with security. Or just any things I should cover when learning about security, finding out about the code / background change was really helpful! Any help of code would be great! Thanks.

Comment: By "security" you mean prevent cross-site scripting, yes?

Comment: Yes, anything that stops people mucking up my site.

Comment: oh... that's what you meant... ok

Answer (score 3):

First, in ColdFusion Administrator, make sure "Enable Global Script Protection" is turned on. (It's under "Server Settings > Settings".)

Next, get and use the UDF [FormStripHTML](http://cflib.org/udf/FormStripHTML). This will allow you to easily "clean up" form submissions. (There is also [RemoveHTML](http://cflib.org/udf/removeHTML), [StripHTML](http://cflib.org/udf/stripHTML) and [SafeText](http://cflib.org/udf/SafeText).) If you need to allow HTML but want to convert it to the appropriate entities, use [HTMLSafe](http://cflib.org/udf/HTMLSafe). (You might also repurpose [NaughtyFilter](http://cflib.org/udf/naughtyFilter) to replace strings you want to disallow. No reason it has to be profanity.) There are also a bunch of rather useful UDFs in the [Security Library](http://cflib.org/library/SecurityLib).

Answer (score 1):

Do a search on [UGTV](http://www.carehart.org/ugtv/index.cfm) with keyword 'secure' or 'security'.  There are great video intros on how to secure your CF app.